# is ther any possiblity to reuse c++ user defined macros /functions in QML or otherwise have a similar definition directly in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have a function macro defined in c++ like below, the benefit here is that the identifier `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, is automatically added to the final call thus original caller signature is captured, I need this also to be the case when I call my final function from QML without manually adding caller prety_type , I cant define a Q_INVOKABE called from QML but if the invoKable takes the rule of invoking the macro I would lost QML caller function signature , I know it should be possible because splodg library has this behavior of showing QML/JS function name .

```
#define my_debug(msg,category) \
    myns::logger->log_debug(msg, category,  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
```

in c++ ,

```
namespace myns{
class logger {
void log_debug(const char* msg , CATEGORY category  , const char* caller_sign = ""){
 ... 
  ...
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to directly call your macro from QML. That is just not possible. But it sounds like that's not real your question. It sounds like you're more interested in just getting the line/function names in your debug output. You can do that easily with [qInstallMessageHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).

Start by defining your message handling function. Qt provides a context object that has all the line/function info you want.

```
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    QByteArray localMsg = msg.toLocal8Bit();
    const char *file = context.file ? context.file : "";
    const char *function = context.function ? context.function : "";
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Debug: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), file, context.line, function);
        break;
    case QtInfoMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Info: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), file, context.line, function);
        break;
    case QtWarningMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), file, context.line, function);
        break;
    case QtCriticalMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), file, context.line, function);
        break;
    case QtFatalMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), file, context.line, function);
        break;
    }
}
```

Then tell Qt to use that function to handle your messages, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    ...
    return app.exec();
}
```

Now when you use qDebug() or console.log(), it should call your output function and you should see the line numbers and function names.

Comment: Thanks for your kind attention @JarMan , but as I said not using Qt debug functions neither console logging ,  and I already implement a message handler for Qt logs , appreaciated!

Comment: The QML logs given by `console.log` are also ending up in a handler such as given in this answer, you should be able to connect your logging system through this handler and using the `context.function` (which should contain qml function) as subsitute for `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`

Comment: @Amfasis, thats the point , if Qt extracts this info from console.log , how can one access these abstract properties in the QML context , getting this info down in c++ is not usefull to me , I need to construct a more detailed log depending on the qml context not c++

Comment: Do I understand correctly you want an all QML solution? I mean, with the above answer you would get something like this: `Debug: hello there (qrc:/main.qml:11, onCompleted)` from a `console.log("hello there")` And you can also read "qml" in `context.category`. It does this via `QQmlEngine::contextForObject`, [see Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#contextForObject)

Comment: @Amfasis, Yes , was not sure what to pass to `QQmlEngine::contextForObject()`  but , it does the job , I could parse qml file name , passing `this` as argument from qml , this worth be a full answer! if you will .

Comment: I still don't fully understand the whole question, so not sure how to phrase my answer. You can also write yourself an answer ;-)